# Can you curve 1 edge without adding more edges to it?

Tags: bezier-curves, edges

I've scoured the internet for how to make a simple, single curve from 1 edge, but apparently that is some monumental task in Blender lol

Here's a picture of what I'm working on:
[image: sleeve]

I'm just trying to curve the selected edge to make it match the green curve to its left

I use Blender pretty much exclusively to rig clothes to 3D models, so about anything outside of that is foreign to me, but I'm trying to slowly venture out to learn more so I can use less other programs

Anyway, is there any way to curve this lone 2D edge without having to add more edges? Everything I saw online mentioned beveling, which as far as I could discern, involved me making and selecting more edges to curve, which won't work, need the number of faces to stay the same and for it all to stay in 2D in this step

Sorry if this is a dumb question, but I seriously cannot find anything that tells me a way to curve a 2D edge, which is driving me insane. I know there has to be some way to do it, even if it's not simple for whatever reason

Thanks

Comment: That's not monumental task in Blender only, that applies to pretty much all 3d programs and is not possible. If you want to curve geometry you need to have some geometry which allow that. Edge consisting of 2 vertices won't curve in any way. There are workarounds though, e.g.  assigning texture with transparency (depends on your task, might not work).

Comment: Thank you for letting me know that a curve isn't really possible lol, that at least lets me try to think of a different way to work around it.....may be able to just add more vertices to the edge and curve it that way, will do it & try.....thank you though, even if the answer isn't what I was hoping for :)

Comment: Just to clarify. An edge is the line that connect two vertices. When creating a mesh, that line can only be straight. To simulate curvature you need to add more vertices and connect them using vertices (and faces) that describe the shape you are after (as you did on the right side of the posted image). There are ["curve objects''](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/curves/index.html) that allow to use just two control points between a curved segment, but I doubt that is what you need for cloth simulation.

Comment: You can try curve modelling if curving edges is more intuitive for you then adding curvature by cutting more edges and moving vertices, but it has one significant drawback. After changing curve to mesh, you gonna get triangulated, pretty nasty geometry.

Answer (score 0):

Just move some of your vertices/edges around like this, if possible for your design. (Select vertice and press G) Then you keep the same number of faces and your vertices end up on the curve.  And your faces are distributed more evenly making cloth simulation more realistic.

[image]